# display field group in different tab/URL

Tags: entities, users, hooks

I have been struggling with this. Views cannot help me (or I didn't figure out how).

I have created a new tab to my profile 2 in my custom module using 
custom_menu 
custom_menu_alter 
custom_menu_local_tasks_alter

The URL is mywebsite.com/profile-main/%user/preferences

*Preferences* is the new URL linked to the new tab.

My aim is to display a field group with a bunch of preferences info in that new tab/URL 
Technically under that tab I want the user to log any preferences they have regarding newsletters and how we contact them etc...(GDPR related stuff) I need the data to be attached to the specific user.

I can't seem to figure it out. I am not very confident with hooks and custom code and at this point I am stuck. What did I miss?

Any clue on how I could achieve this?

I am using Drupal 7. What I want is to move fields (in a field group) from the main profile 2 registration page form and display them in the new tab accessible when logged in to profile 2 account, instead of having everything in the same form. But I am happy to have to create a different form if it would work better. This is what's returned by custom menu:

```
$items['profile-main/%user/preferences'] = array(
  'title' => t(' Preferences'), 
  'page callback' => 'custom_user_preferences', 
  'page arguments' => array(1), // Uid 
  'access callback' => TRUE, 
  'access arguments' => array('access candidate_dashboard'), 
  'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK, 
);
```

This is the array for custom_user_preferences:

```
'custom_user_preferences' => array(
  'file' => 'includes/user_preferences.inc', 
  'template' => 'templates/user_preferences', 
  'variables' => array(
    'profile' => NULL, 
    'approved' => NULL, 
    'cust_type' => NULL,
  ) 
),
```

**edit:**
Am I right to assume that I have to

1. programmatically create a form
2. which upon submission saves the data in relevant profile2 fields
3. display the form in the new path I created

**edit 11/jan**

In the end I am creating a form as the fields I need to add are not in the profile 2 set up to start with (the profile 2 registration form has more than 180 fields in it). 
I've been receiving error:

```
*Warning: Illegal string offset '#tree' in form_builder() (line 1891 of /**/**/**/site/includes/form.inc).
Warning: Illegal string offset '#tree' in form_builder() (line 1911 of /**/**/**/site/includes/form.inc).
Warning: Illegal string offset '#parents' in form_builder() (line 1911 of /**/**/**/site/includes/form.inc).
Notice: Array to string conversion in form_builder() (line 1911 of /**/**/**/site/includes/form.inc).
Warning: Illegal string offset '#array_parents' in form_builder() (line 1916 of /**/**/**/site/includes/form.inc).
Notice: Array to string conversion in form_builder() (line 1916 of /**/**/**/site/includes/form.inc).
Warning: Illegal string offset '#weight' in form_builder() (line 1920 of /**/**/**/site/includes/form.inc).
Warning: Illegal string offset '#processed' in form_builder() (line 1802 of /**/**/**/site/includes/form.inc).
Error: Unsupported operand types in form_builder() (line 1812 of /**/**/**/site/includes/form.inc).*
```

I am not sure if the problem is my form or the callback or something else...

```
function site_menu() {
    $items = array();
    $items['profile-main/%user/preferences'] = array(
        'title' => t(' Preferences'),
        'page callback' => drupal_get_form,
        'page arguments' => array('site_upload_form', 1), // Uid
        'access callback' => TRUE,
        'access arguments' => array('access content'),
        'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    );
}

function site_upload_form($form, &$form_state){
    $form['email']= array(
        '#type'=>'textfield',
        '#title'=>t('Confirm email address'),
        '#maxlength'=> 255,
        '#required'=> TRUE,
    );
    $form['frequencyemail']= array(
        '#type'=>'select',
        '#title'=> t('How often do you want to hear from us?'),
        '#options'=> array(
            0 =>'Regularly',
            1 => 'Quarterly',
            2 => 'During the Summit',
            3 => 'Never',
            ),
        '#required'=> TRUE,
    );

    $form['submit']= array(
        '#type'=>'submit',
         '#value'=> t('Submit'),
     );
return $form;
}
```

Not sure what I am looking for

Comment: Hi! Are you on Drupal 7 or 8? Can you also clarify what you want to achieve? Sounds like you want some sort of a configuration *form* at `/profile-main/%user/preferences`, but not quite sure. In your `custom_menu` what are you returning for that path?

Comment: Drupal 7
What I want is to move fields (in a field group) from the main profile 2 registration page form and display them in the new tab accessible when logged in to profile 2 account,  instead of having everything in the same form. Does that make sense?
But I am happy to have to create a different form if it would work better.
This is what's returned by custom menu: See below

Comment: $items['profile-main/%user/preferences'] = array(
     'title' => t(' Preferences'),
     'page callback' => 'custom_user_preferences',
     'page arguments' => array(1), // Uid
     'access callback' => TRUE,
     'access arguments' => array('access candidate_dashboard'),
     'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
   );

Comment: this is the array for custom_user_preferences:
'custom_user_preferences' => array(
   'file'  => 'includes/user_preferences.inc',
   'template' => 'templates/user_preferences',
   'variables' => array(
    'profile' => NULL,
    'approved' => NULL,
    'cust_type' => NULL,)
  ),

Comment: Please edit the original question to add details as comments can get purged and readability isn't great ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is correct I suppose! You might want to remove the said fields from the original profile edit form additionally.

I hope you're familiar with Form API! Take a look at [`user_profile_form`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.pages.inc/function/user_profile_form/7.x). This function is the main form function for the profile form. This form calls [`user_account_form`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_account_form/7.x) function and passes the `$form` variable by reference, and in `user_account_form` the profile fields are created and put into the `$form` variable.

So:

1. Programmatically create a new form. If I were you, I'd just call `user_account_form` from here too, but then unset the fields you don't want. The form could also call the default validate and submit handlers then:
   `$form['#validate'][] = 'user_profile_form_validate';`
   and `$form['#submit'][] = 'user_profile_form_submit';`
2. `hook_form_alter` to alter the original `user_profile_form` and `unset` the fields which you are showing in your other form. (Or you can set `'#access' => false` too)
3. Show the form at the path you created. This is just a case of returning `drupal_get_form` as your `page callback` and your form ID as `page arguments`. Or you can `return drupal_get_form('your_form_id');` from your `page callback` function. Whatever works for you.

Comment: I have used form API a bit. For some reason I missed user_profile_form. I will look into that. Thank you for the hints.

Comment: Hmm I suspect the code for my form is problematic... Because the tab displays and when I click on it it directs me to the right path - just nothing is showing there. I suspect my form is wrong. (I updated the initial question with the error message)

Comment: @NanaBrownee are you on PHP7? IIRC Drupal 7 doesn't fully support PHP7. Try with PHP5. Also don't forget to clear your cache. (Also just an observation but you're not taking the `$uid` variable in your form function)